# Stop character on Platform with collision when falling: AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a platform game. At the moment I am just trying to create gravity, and platforms. I've got the gravity down pat, but when my character (player) collides with the platform, he instantly appears back at the top of the screen and falls down again, and it just keeps repeating each time the player touches the platform. Here's my code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;


public class GameCode extends MovieClip {

    var upKey:Boolean;
    var leftKey:Boolean;
    var rightKey:Boolean;
    var jump:Boolean = false;

    var xvelocity:int = 10;
    var yvelocity:int = 0;
    var gravity:Number = 7;

    var startPosY:int;
    var startPosX:int;
    var lastPosY:int;
    var lastPosX:int;

    public function GameCode() {
        // constructor code
    }

    public function startGame(){
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeyUp);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    function update(evt:Event){
        moveCharacter();
        yvelocity += gravity;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if (!platform.hitTestObject(player)){
                player.y = yvelocity;
            }
            if (platform.hitTestObject(player)){
                yvelocity = 0;
                player.y--;
            }
        }
    }

    function moveCharacter(){
        lastPosY = player.y;
        lastPosX = player.x;

        if (leftKey == true){
            player.x -= xvelocity;
        }
        if (rightKey == true){
            player.x += xvelocity;
        }
        if (upKey == true){
            if (jump == true){
                player.y
            }
        }
    }

    function checkKeyDown(evt:KeyboardEvent){
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            leftKey = true;
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            rightKey = true;
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
            upKey = true;
        }
    }

    function checkKeyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent){
        if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
            leftKey = false;
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
            rightKey = false;
        }
        else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
            upKey = false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

My character's instance name is player and my platforms instance is simply just platform.
Obviously, I would like help on how to change this; What I want is for the character to fall with gravity, land on the platform, be able to move around, and when falling off the character falls off to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is here :

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if (!platform.hitTestObject(player)){
        player.y = yvelocity;  // if yvelocity == 0, then so will the player's y
    }
    if (platform.hitTestObject(player)){
        yvelocity = 0;
        player.y--;
    }
}
```

You should be checking each platform for a collision and if one occurs handle that accordingly and break out of the loop.

You should be incrementing your player.y by yvelocity BEFORE the loop.

```
player.y += yvelocity;
```

In the case of a collision you should be setting the player.y so that the player's feet are standing on the platform. Assuming the platform's origin point is in the top left of the platform and the player.y is the level with the player's feet you'd do something like this :

```
player.y = platform.y - 1;
```

I won't code this out for you, but the logic should help get you there.

I'd also like to note that this implementation doesn't account for what part of the body is colliding with the platform. So if the player jumped and his head collided with a platform, he'd pop to the top of the platform.

Also, if the player is able to move left/right while falling and moves into a block with either side of his body , he'd pop to the top of the platform.

You should google "as3 platform game tutorial" or something of that nature as some of these concepts would likely be discussed in greater detail, including solutions.